# Set local system as Windows service identity

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I've been all over Google, trying to find a way (in PowerShell) to set LocalSystem as the LogOn identity for a Windows service.
All scripts/functions I found are for setting a "real user", I need to set LocalSystem

Just to clarify, I am talking about an existing service, not installing a new service. I would create it this way but I have no control over the creation of the service.

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The SYSTEM acocunt is `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` or just `SYSTEM`.

Comment: The default for a service is Local System so you might just need to change the way you initially create the service.

Comment: I added some clarification, this is not about installing a new service. How do I "unflag" the duplicate?